# Get name of selected country from jQuery Vector Maps

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Im trying to use jQuery Vector Maps.

Everything works but i just dont know how i can get name of clicked country. I need this to use that name country in my different jQuery code.

Here is simple documentation: http://jvectormap.com/documentation/javascript-api-v1/jvm-worldmap/

I think that i will have to use: getMapObject

But how i have to use it? Where put this getCode?

Answer (score 3):

I did it with this code

```
$(function(){
  $('#world-map').vectorMap({
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    map: 'world_map',
    series: {
      regions: [{
        values: countryDamage,
        scale: ['#FFEECF', '#FF2C2C'],
        normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
      }]
    },
    onRegionClick: function(event, code){
        var map = $('#world-map').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
        alert(map.getRegionName(code));
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
    <script>                
        $('.map_jvector').vectorMap({
          map: 'your_name_map',
          backgroundColor: '#ffffff',

          onRegionClick:function(event, code){            
           var name = (code);                          
            alert(name);
            }             
        });

    </script>
```