# Getting country name from jVectormap World Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jvectormap

How i can get name of clicked country from jVectormap?

I using simple code, added alert to show the name of clicked country but doesn't work.

```
jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({
    map: 'world_en',
    backgroundColor: '#e9e9e7',
    color: '#dfdfdd',
    hoverOpacity: 0,
    selectedColor: '#5f8b98',
    hoverColor: '#5f8b98',
    enableZoom: true,
    showTooltip: true,
    values: sample_data,
    scaleColors: ['#dfdfdd'],
    onRegionClick: function (event, code) {
    var map = $('#vmap').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
    var name = map.getRegionName(code);
    //ADDED ALERT TO SHOW NAME OF CLICKED COUNTRY
    alert(name);
    },
    normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
});
```

Here is the documentation of using script:
http://jvectormap.com/documentation/javascript-api-v1/jvm-worldmap/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get name of selected country from jQuery Vector Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585636/get-name-of-selected-country-from-jquery-vector-maps)

Comment: Nope i added there my code..

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code, I've setup a jsFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/9Vyv6/ Do you have any javascript errors ?

Comment: Your code works fine. I know because I solved my problems using your code example.

Answer (score 1):

What does "it does not work" mean?
Do you get an error? Or what do you get in the alert?

Not tested, but you could try to do it this way:

```
var mymap = new jvm.WorldMap({
  container: $('#vmap'),
  ...
  onRegionClick: function (event, code) {
    alert(mymap.getRegionName(code));
  }
});
```

Comment: Its weird, because with my code alert doesnt work. It just dont appear, instead of alert colors on map are changing. Dont know why. When i click on map, color of this country change (and dont thing of my css colors).

Ur code doesnt work, nothing happens. Where i have to put this code?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 onRegionClick:function(event, code) {                        
        var name = (code);                        
        alert(name);                    
        }
```

All Script

```
    jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({
        map: 'world_en',
        backgroundColor: '#e9e9e7',
        color: '#dfdfdd',
        hoverOpacity: 0,
        selectedColor: '#5f8b98',
        hoverColor: '#5f8b98',
        enableZoom: true,
        showTooltip: true,
        values: sample_data,
        scaleColors: ['#dfdfdd'],
        //alert
        onRegionClick:function(event, code) {                         
        var name = (code);                        
        alert(name);                    
        },
        normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
    });
```